# Sort five columns of data

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to create a formula or something with VBA to help me sort five columns of data.

I’ll briefly explain – I use video games to learn languages, and I’m trying to create a multi-subtitle system for Baldur’s Gate 3. The text is organized via Content UIDs (for all languages). Unfortunately, in each language file the UIDs are not ordered the same, so I am unable to sort and align them to combine them into one cell.

Here is an example of the cells and the UIDs:

<content contentuid="h000006d4gcefbg4092gbb39gfeb27a3bb0a7" version="1">Sorry, darling, I haven't got time for underlings.</content>

<content contentuid="h000006d4gcefbg4092gbb39gfeb27a3bb0a7" version="1">抱歉，亲爱的，我可没时间搭理下属。</content>

<content contentuid="h000006d4gcefbg4092gbb39gfeb27a3bb0a7" version="1">Lo siento, cielo, no tengo tiempo para subordinados.</content>

<content contentuid="h000006d4gcefbg4092gbb39gfeb27a3bb0a7" version="1">Прости, моя радость, со слугами не разговариваю.</content>

<content contentuid="h000006d4gcefbg4092gbb39gfeb27a3bb0a7" version="1">Désolé, très cher, je n'ai pas de temps à perdre avec les sous-fifres.</content>

And here is what I want it to look like :

<content contentuid="h000006d4gcefbg4092gbb39gfeb27a3bb0a7" version="1">Sorry, darling, I haven't got time for underlings. || RU: Извините, дорогая, у меня нет времени для подчиненных. || ES: Lo siento, cariño, no tengo tiempo para los subordinados. || FR: Désolé, chérie, je n'ai pas le temps pour les subalternes. || ZH: 抱歉，亲爱的，我没有时间的下降时间。</content>

There are over 200,000 of these lines of dialogue. My question - is there any way to have the other four columns (B-E) align in order using Column A as a reference using the unique UIDs?

Here is an example Google Sheet of what it currently looks like (and want I want it to look like):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uTs2X55uEPkAHA_wPS-D0iQ8Ea9OXRRAd8eAzalNiBc/edit?usp=sharing

Hopefully someone knows how to do this, because AI is not up to the task yet!

Many times with AI, but they all gave me unhelpful solutions.

Comment: But did all these AIs produce at least a line of code that you tried? Or have you tried to imagine a process for all the inputs? An index/match for multiple columns (with left to get the UID) along with  substitute formulas could do the trick.

Comment: There is no need to do this with VBA. Insert one column after each language. In cell B2 type this formula `=MID(A2;21;39)` . Drag it tlll the end of the list. This will give you a column with the keys from column A. Do this for the rest of the lanuages just by replacing the column letter to the corresponding. Do a custom sort on every language by using the next column with the keys. Delete the inserted columns and you are done.

Comment: @mits great answer! You've helped me get super close to what I'm looking for. I've got one problem to overcome - Column A (English) has more cells than the others, so when I sort I don't know how to factor for the empty spaces that should show up in Columns B-E (because ENG has UIDs that the other languages do not have). Does this make sense? Thanks for your help!

Comment: May I ask. Do you really need the ENG UIDs that don't exist in the other languages? If the use is for learning languages, then it seems like these are not so useful.

Comment: Technically I don't need them, but I'm using the English UIDs as a reference against all the others. Because if I exclude them then the whole process become so much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your table into

| Language | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| English | ... |
| English | ... |
| Russian | ... |

Then you can add a column for the contentuid, language prefix, and translation. Sort and group that and you have your result.

I would use power-query for this. Highlight your data, click "Data - From Table" in the ribbon, and a query editor will pop up that has an unpivot button!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using formulas. VBA and Power Query are also possible options.

| Cell | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | =MID(A2,21,39) |
| C1 | =XLOOKUP(B2,F:F,E:E,"") |
| D1 | =IFERROR(MID(C2,SEARCH(">",C2)+1,SEARCH("<",C2,2)-SEARCH(">",C2)-1),"") |
|  |  |
| F1 | =MID(E2,21,39) |
| G1 | =SUBSTITUTE(A2,"</",CONCAT(" || ",$D$1,": ",D2,"</")) |

The result is on column G.

[image]

---

**Update**

> Question - if I want to add additional languages to the spreadsheet, any idea how would that work

> Answer: It is easy to expand the template.

Step1: Copy column C:F and insert before column G. You will get 4 columns with all formulas. It is for new language subtitle.

Step2: Paste new subtitle into column I.

Step3: Update H1 with language code (Russian >> RU)

Step4: Update formulas in column K to concate all subtitle text.

Comment: This is brilliant, got it working thank you! Now I need to do the same with Russian, Spanish and French  and combine them all in the same sheet. So quick question - if I want to add additional languages to the spreadsheet, any idea how would that work?

Comment: Please have a look updated post. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you, got this working last night. Unfortunately the cells are not aligning and I have different UIDs all mixed up with each other.

Comment: `UIDs` is the key to connect different language subtitle. What does `different UIDs all mixed up` mean?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am trying to use the UIDs to match the different language subtitles. The UIDs are linked to scenes in the video game, and unfortunately they are not in the same order.

Here is an example of the error - <content contentuid="h00189193gc0d0g4295gb932g269d08d8ce8e" version="1">Entrance |RU| Я знаю, Ролан на меня в обиде. |FR| Je sais. Rolan a une dent contre moi. |ESP| Cola A |ZH| 坐下，利爪 ！坏女孩！</content>


I've also updated the Google Sheet linked in my original post with some sample data in Sheet 2. Thanks for your ongoing help, really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Do you mean merged cells in row 50?

Comment: No it's that different UIDs are being merged together. I want all of the same UIDs across the 5 languages to be merged together and that isn't happening.

Comment: I haven't seen the formula which were integrated in worksheet and don't know which part is wrong.